# Problemas al mostrar la hora en un TextView se cierra aplicación

Tags: android, datepicker

Estoy usando un calendario con `DatePickerDialog`, pero al dar en aceptar no se asigna la fecha seleccionada a la variable.

```
private void popupMuestraCalendario(final String funcion) {

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                String myFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"; // your format
                String formato = "yyyy-MM-dd";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());
                SimpleDateFormat formatoInsert = new SimpleDateFormat(formato, Locale.getDefault());

                if(funcion.equals("inicio")){
                    tv_fecha_inicio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fechainicio);
                    tv_fecha_inicio.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                    fecha_inicio = formatoInsert.format(calendar.getTime());
                }else{
                    tv_fecha_fin = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fechafin);
                    tv_fecha_fin.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                    fecha_fin = formatoInsert.format(calendar.getTime());
                }
            }

        };

        new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),date,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
```

Se cae la app, esto me muestra el logcat.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.projects.brightblade.fatigasx, PID:
>   25560 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference
>   atcom.projects.brightblade.fatigasx.FatigasFragment$4.onDate‌​Set(FatigasFragment.‌​java:138
>   at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:1‌​71)
>   atcom.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.han‌​dleMessage(AlertCont‌​roller.java:175)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Comment: Remueve "final" de **final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();**

Comment: Cuando te refieres que no se asigna la fecha, se cae la app o muestra en blanco, etc. Que te muestra tu logcat?

Comment: Hola Juan, como comenta @AshleyG. Tienes algún error ya que no veo un error en el método!

Comment: ¿Los `textView` no están en la misma Activity del método `onDateSet`?

Comment: @Reynald0 al momento de quitarle el final me marca error y pide que la variable la haga final

Comment: @AshleyG. se cae la app, esto me muestra el logcat.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.projects.brightblade.fatigasx, PID: 25560
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
atcom.projects.brightblade.fatigasx.FatigasFragment$4.onDateSet(FatigasFragment.java:138
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:171)
atcom.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:175)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Comment: Alguno de tus TextView tv_fecha_inicio o tv_fecha_fin es nulo, ya los inicializaste en el onCreate?

Comment: @JUANPABLOSANGAR agregué el error a tu pregunta, todas las actualizaciones de información agregalas, agregué respuesta, saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano los TextView están declarados en la misma clase.

Comment: Ya quedó amigos, gracias por su ayuda :)

Comment: Por favor no agregue "gracias" como respuesta. Mejor, **[acepte la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que le parecio mas útil. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/80897)

Answer (score 0):

En realidad tu AlertDialog no debe tener ningun problema tanto para mostrarse como para configurar la hora, el error en realidad es:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>   atcom.projects.brightblade.fatigasx.FatigasFragment$4.onDate‌​Set(FatigasFragment.‌​java:138
>   at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:1‌​71)

y es causado porque las referencias de los `TextViews` no existen:

```
tv_fecha_inicio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fechainicio);
tv_fecha_fin = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fechafin);
```

revisa el archivo que cargas mediante `setContent()` y este debe tener los `TextView` con ids `tv_fechainicio` y `tv_fechafin`

Comment: de hecho el AlertDialog sale sin problemas, y de hecho la asignación de la variable al textView si está, pero no la quiere reconocer, la deja en nulo...

Comment: Exacto el AlertDialog no tiene problema, debes asegurar que los TextView se encuentren en el layout, es una activity? que .xml carga mediante setContentView() revisalo.